# Add stopwatch to a SharePoint Online Task list

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list

How can I capture current time spend on the task from start date in SharePoint Task list?

Comment: I have added this formula "=(NOW()-Created)*24", to a calculated column, but I get the result in -0.4565645645 !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did some progress, I made the Start & Finish Buttons in IP, and when I checked the values in SPO, for about 30 minutes everything was working fine, and I was getting 2 different values in the 2 columns. But after 30 minutes, both columns becomes showing the same value. The old items were different columns, but upon editing them they become same too :(